# Create virtualenv no such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I am working on mac machine and have one project having virtual env and working perfectly.
now for other project I am trying to create other virtual env in other folder.

```
virtualenv checkenv
```

Saying -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

When I give command

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

It says requirement already satisfied,

Any suggestion,
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the exact error message you get?

Comment: try pip install virtualenv

Comment: what is the call path when you use "virtualenv checkenv"? Re-installing virtualenv globally should not make any difference because local (cwd env) is checked first before global packages

Comment: virtualenv checkenv   getting same error -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: So, do you have a `/usr/bin/python/`?

Comment: yes I do have python3 python3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/usr/local/bin/virtualen` had likely been created with system macOS Python 2.7, which has been discontinued and removed from the latest macOS versions.  Remove outdated `/usr/local/bin/virtualen` wrapper and reinstall *virtualenv* package (or try `pip3 install --upgrade`): *pip3* will create new wrapper script, but **only when *virtualenv* module is installed**.  If *pip* (*pip3* is an executable name) finds installed package, it skips installation and doesn't check for symlink and wrapper validity.